# Why is youtube-dl still downloading video with 'keepvideo':False?

Tags: python, youtube-dl

I'm trying to download just the thumbnail of a video and it does download the thumbnail but the video also downloads afterwards. I'm using this code:

```
 thumbnail = folder + video["title"]
    tn_options={
    'format':'bestvideo',
    'keepvideo':False,
    'writethumbnail':'writethumbnail',
    'outtmpl':thumbnail,}
    
    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(tn_options) as ydl:
        ydl.download([video['webpage_url']])
```

I assumed that setting keepvideo to False would prevent downloading the video as I've used it in the past but it's not working in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The option to not download any video is called `skip_download`. It would be like the following:

```py
thumbnail = folder + video["title"]
tn_options={
  'format': 'bestvideo',
  'skip_download': True,
  'writethumbnail': 'writethumbnail',
  'outtmpl': thumbnail,
}

with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(tn_options) as ydl:
  ydl.download([video['webpage_url']])
```

`keepvideo` is a [post-processing video-only flag](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/#post-processing-options). If `True` it means that it would keep the original video besides the post-processed one after finished.

From the docs:

> Keep the video file on disk after the post-processing; the video is erased by default.

Comment: But is there anyway to prevent the video from downloading in the first place to lower the amount of time when scaling this for multiple thumbnails/videos.

Comment: Yes, there is. I've updated the answer with it.